# Unable to Connect to Dynamics 365(On-Premise) with IFD authentication

Tags: connection, authorization, dynamics-crm, crm

I have one Dynamics CRM 365(On-Premise) environment with IFD authentication. I am trying to perform operations on CRM with sdk. I am doing test connection first and store that test connection in a cache object. This cache object is of type `IDictionary`. I am struggling with a strange issue. For different instances it will create different proxy and cache them.

Scenarios:
1) Auth type is Federation - It will take this live id and discovery url and create on Key using MD5 algo and store in IDictionary so next time when I perform any operation it will check for proxy in cache. If cache is true it will take proxy from cache and continue.

This works as expected in dev but in production I have one strange issue.
Suppose for day 1 it establish connection when auth type is AD the it works with only that type of connection for whole day even if I am giving discovery url for Federation.

Next time when I try suppose on day 2 or if I close the app and again open then this time it is not working for same configuration.

I am too confused what is happening exactly.

code for Connection:

```
private CrmServiceClient CreateServiceClient(AuthenticationProviderType _endpointType, IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> organizationServiceManagement)
        {
            AuthCredentials = GetCredentials(_endpointType);
            string connectionString = string.Empty;
            string organizationUri = OrganizationServiceManagement.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri
                .Replace(OrganizationServiceManagement.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Address.Uri.AbsolutePath, string.Empty);
            switch (_endpointType)
            {
                case AuthenticationProviderType.None:
                    break;
                case AuthenticationProviderType.ActiveDirectory:
                    connectionString = $"AuthType=AD;Url={ organizationUri }/{ AuthInfo.OrganizationUniqueName} ; Domain={ AuthInfo.Domain } ; Username={ AuthInfo.UserName }; Password ={ AuthInfo.Password }";
                    break;
                case AuthenticationProviderType.Federation:
                    connectionString = $"AuthType=IFD;ServiceUri={ organizationUri }/{ AuthInfo.OrganizationUniqueName };Domain={ AuthInfo.Domain };Username={ AuthInfo.Domain }\\{ AuthInfo.UserName };Password={ AuthInfo.Password };";
                    break;
                case AuthenticationProviderType.LiveId:
                    break;
                case AuthenticationProviderType.OnlineFederation:
                    connectionString = $"AuthType=Office365;Username={AuthInfo.UserName}; Password={AuthInfo.Password}; Url={organizationUri}";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            var serviceClient = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
            return serviceClient;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by __Auth type is Federation__? There are 2 authentication types for on-premises: AD and IFD.

Comment: Please post some basic code. I'm having a very hard time understanding why you are caching anything in an `IDictionary` that would be related to authentication type.

Comment: @Nicknow ..Auth type is IFD. I am caching it because i dont want it to establish connection each and every time for each request.

Comment: You don't need to cache it. Call `new CrmServiceClient("...conn string...")` when you need a connection - it handles all the caching for you.

Comment: @Nicknow - I was doing cache just because i dont want to do the test connection for each and every request. One more thing i want to confirm is if i am creating a new connection for each request what will be its drawback and what will happen in case of multiple instance? Service will work properly or there is a possibility that it will crash?

Comment: I'm not aware of any drawback to creating a new connection object (it can, if still valid, reuse the security token and metadata download.) I'm not sure why it would crash, I guess that is always a possibility in code but I wouldn't expect that behavior. My suggestion, if you have a particular concern, is to write a test to replicate the scenario.

Comment: @Nicknow Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. It works when i create a new connection every time but i am still confused why it is showing that kind of odd behavior.Still unable to find the actual cause.

Comment: @Nicknow..I hope you remember this issue. I had updated this question and added basic code for connection. Can you help me for a permanent fix?